# Spring jpa get method giving extra slashes

Tags: json, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring JPA repository to get records from table which stores few file systems paths as column values.
I am using findAll method , but problem is when i get JSON output it appends extra slashes.
I get value like ...
"\\computerName\monitor",
When the value in the table is \computerName\monitor.

Is there any way i can avoid extra slashes in json response.

Regards,

Comment: value in the table is "\\computerName\monitor"  ... without quotes ..

Comment: Can you add Repository/DAO code to your post

Comment: This is just how JSON works. Backslashes must be escaped in JSON strings. Because they're used for escapes (\n is a newline, \t is a tab, etc.). Your JSON parser will remove those backslashes. That has absolutely nothing to do with JPA, BTW, which doesn't use JSON at all.

Comment: JB Nizet, 

Actually you are right ,i was testing my endpoint on postman and output was showing as \\\\computerName\\monitor but as per ur your suggestion i tried with json.parse in javascript and output looks fine its kinda of weird.
Actually i was thinking there may be some annotation for telling entity field to not to add extra slashes. Anyways thanks a lot. I will try to mark your answer as correct answer